# How to exclude certain files from a package managed by jspm and systemjs?

Tags: systemjs, jspm

For instance with bower I could do something like this to get only the scss files (excluding js):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap-sass": {
      "main": [
        "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am having an hard time understanding how to do it with [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). in the config.js file I guess but even reading [the docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170402205628/https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md) I could not figure it out.

My use case is: while developing I am loading [Material angular](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) with systemjs but I want to load only the js files, not the css, which I want to manage indenpdently in my scss. Instead systemjs keep loading the file `angular-material.css`. I just started with systemjs and [jspm](https://jspm.org/), hope you can help.

nb: my problem is not related to the jspm build or bundle process but to the development time with these tools.

Answer (score 1):

JSPM supports overrides as well. See https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#testing-configuration for configuration options.

Using JSPM overrides you can easily override the main file and directories and files that you need from a module.

Upd. The css dependency is defined in the registry: https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/974beb8b6520f4c1b3c6373db32ad05da5c82446/package-overrides/github/angular/bower-material%400.4.0.json It needs to be overwritten with the local override.

Comment: Thanks Oleksii, now I have in my package.json the following
`"jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "angular-material": "github:angular/bower-material@^1.1.1",
    },
    "overrides": {
      "github:angular/bower-material@1.1.1": {
        "main": "angular-material.js"
      }
    }
  }`
but systemjs keeps loading the `angular-material.css` file, any idea how to stop that?

Comment: If you take a look at your package.json, you will see that the css file is listed as a dependency to the file angular-material.js. Simply remove it and run jspm install again. When you install packages with jspm you should also keep in mind that there is public registry of overrides to fix packages which are not made to work with jspm: https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/974beb8b6520f4c1b3c6373db32ad05da5c82446/package-overrides/github/angular/bower-material%400.4.0.json

Comment: in neither my `package.json` nor in my `systemjs.config.js` files there is any reference of `angular-material.css`, I guess systemjs just look at the config files of the package `angular-material` in the `jspm_packages` folder and determine what to load and what I miss now is how to override this.

Comment: I am using the beta version of jspm: https://gist.github.com/OrKoN/e352ee9ca553e54c8891d4363c10e162

Comment: Ah, that is totally different package.json then mine, I will take a look tomorrow, thanks!